# css padding adjustment for home button

Tags: css

This is my footer menu home button icon, but the home button is displayed without any space  in left side.

**css**

```
#footer-menu{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:auto;
}

#footer-menu  .homeButton a{

    background:url('http://w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif');
    background-position:left top;
    height:20px;
    padding:5px 18px 20px 28px; 
    border:none;
    width:38px;
}

#footer-menu .homeButton a:hover{
    background:url('http://w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites_hover.gif');
    background-position:0 -45px; 
}
```

I have given padding values, but it will not move to right side. The home button I had got from w3schools. please give good home button.

Comment: 1>before using w3schools please visit www.w3fools.com
2>you should give us a live example like jsfiddle or atleast a picture[snapshot] else we wont understand what is your actual problem and what u are wanting....

Comment: Hi can you paste you HTML as well? it would be even better if you visit http://fiddle.jshell.net/ and create a live demo for us to see. So we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer-menu  .homeButton {

   margin-left:20px;
}
```

it is my guess only as you didnot give us any live example like [jsfiidle](http://www.jsfiddle.com/) or any snapshots.so it is very hard to guess what you are actually having now and what you want

Comment: Dear Gautam,it is working now.Thanks for ur big help.

Comment: @user3687356 if it helped you please chose it as a correct answer